# Using Facebook Connect with jQTouch?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, jqtouch

I'm starting a new jQTouch-project now and I'm thinking about using Facebook connect to make it easier for users to register with my site. Does anyone have any experience with this?

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK (from [github](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)), and I first tried to use it with the built in example, it worked well.

Later, I tried it with jQTouch (the latest build from the SVN). When I created the log in/log out link inside a `ul.rounded>li` element it does not work because jQTouch have some special function that handles links clicked inside a li-element.  How can i go around this function and make it work with the connect-link? I'm using the display=touch version of the authentication dialog.

When I add the link outside of the `ul.rounded>li-element` it works in desktop Safari but not in mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the link outside the LI, put it outside the UL. It should work because is inside the form tag. I did this in using the beta 2 release and worked.

```
<form id="yourlogin" method="post">
    <ul class="edit rounded">
        <li><input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" id="username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="input"/></li>
        <li><input type="password" name="yourpassword" placeholder="Password" id="yourpassword" class="input" />
        </li>
    </ul> <a name="action" id="loginbtn" style="" href="#" type="submit" class="submit whiteButton">Login</a>
```